# Get MCC/MNC id by entering phone number in Android

Tags: android, carrier, mcc

I am trying to find how to get a MCC/MNC id code (also called PLMN code) 
for a given cellphone number in Android. I am trying to determine which carrier the number is on before making a call.

Comment: And your question is? What have you tried?

Comment: I can answer your question.... but do tell us what have you tried ? And yes you can determine the MCC/MNC/LAC/CID

Comment: i am also trying to do this. Have you got solution to do this? or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve the MCC/MNC for your own phone, not for that of any given cellular number:

```
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();

    if (networkOperator != null) {
        int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
        int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
    }
```

Phone calls are targeted at a PHONE number, regardless of the MCC/MNC of the receiving device. Unless you can obtain access to a third-party database to resolve a phone number to an operator, you're out of luck here. I'm unaware of any such database.